# Translation of "Über kompakte homogene Kählersche Mannigfaltigkeiten"

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, several-complex-variables

Has anyone translated Borel and Remmert's 1962 paper titled:
*Über kompakte homogene Kählersche Mannigfaltigkeiten*?

Comment: If such a translation does not exist, I appreciate if someone give me a reference to a proof of the main theorem: Homogeneous compact kahler manifolds are the direct product of a complex torus and a projective-rational manifold ( It is assumed that the group of all holomorphic transformations of such a manifold is transitive.

Comment: A perhaps stupid comment, but I have used successfully automatic translation (e.g. Google translate, or Babylon) to translate from German, even if I do not know German. It is relatively easy, given it is math and not fiction so you know what to expect, and it works fine if you don't count that it is tedious and time consuming.